# implicit declaration of function ‘gmtime_r’

Tags: c, gcc, posix, time.h

What do I need to do to make `gcc` include the declaration of `gmtime_r(3)` from `time.h`? Looking at `/usr/include/time.h`, `gmtime_r` and `localtime_r` are inside `#ifdef __USE_POSIX`.

Do I need to do something to turn `__USE_POSIX` on, like a command-line option? I'm running with `-std=c99` now. I understand that `__USE_*` macros are not intended to be set directly by user code.

```
/* Return the `struct tm' representation of *TIMER
   in Universal Coordinated Time (aka Greenwich Mean Time).  */
extern struct tm *gmtime (const time_t *__timer) __THROW;

/* Return the `struct tm' representation
   of *TIMER in the local timezone.  */
extern struct tm *localtime (const time_t *__timer) __THROW;

#ifdef __USE_POSIX
/* Return the `struct tm' representation of *TIMER in UTC,
   using *TP to store the result.  */
extern struct tm *gmtime_r (const time_t *__restrict __timer,
                struct tm *__restrict __tp) __THROW;

/* Return the `struct tm' representation of *TIMER in local time,
   using *TP to store the result.  */
extern struct tm *localtime_r (const time_t *__restrict __timer,
                   struct tm *__restrict __tp) __THROW;
#endif  /* POSIX */
```

Comment: I gave it an up-vote, although someone's down-vote is still there.

Comment: If you're compiling in strict mode and want to use posix, gnu, etc. functions on Linux, you should read http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/feature_test_macros.7.html

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The proper way to do this is:

```
#define _POSIX_C_SOURCE 200112L
#include <time.h>
```

This method indicates explicitly the features that a source file requires, making it self-contained. It is also portable to any POSIX system using any compiler. No special compiler flag is needed.

With GCC this code will compile with -std=c89, -std=c99, or any other value. Importantly what -std=gnu?? enables by default might differ depending on version or platform.

See [Feature Test Macros](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Feature-Test-Macros.html#Feature-Test-Macros) for details.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, `gmtime_r` is not part of the ISO C99 standard, it’s a POSIX extension. To enable that, use `std=gnu99` standard.

You can always verify which features are available for which standard on your system by applying technique from [this Pixelbeat article](http://www.pixelbeat.org/programming/gcc/c_c++_notes.html):

> It can be quite confusing sometimes to know exactly
>   what is #defined in your program, and this is especially
>   true for glibc's "feature" macros. These macros are documented
>   (info libc "feature test macros"), but it's much easier
>   to see what's defined directly using "cpp -dD" like:
>
> ```
> $ echo "#include <features.h>" | cpp -dN | grep "#define __USE_"
>     #define __USE_ANSI
>     #define __USE_POSIX
>     #define __USE_POSIX2
>     #define __USE_POSIX199309
>     #define __USE_POSIX199506
>     #define __USE_MISC
>     #define __USE_BSD
>     #define __USE_SVID
>
> $ echo "#include <features.h>" | cpp -dN -std=c99 | grep "#define __USE_"
>     #define __USE_ANSI
>     #define __USE_ISOC99
> ```
>
> Also to see all the predefined macros one can do:
>
> ```
> $ cpp -dM /dev/null
> ```
>
> Note also for compiler specific macros you can do:
>
> ```
> $ gcc -E -dM - < /dev/null
> ```

Comment: Wow, it never occurred to me that `c99` would turn off POSIX features. It's even harder for me to follow that `gnu99` turns them on, I think of `-std=gnu*` as GNU extensions like naked `asm()` statements. But you're right, `gnu99` forces these macros and pulls in the function I'm looking for.

Comment: @iter in Standard C the user could make their own function called `gmtime_r` with a different prototype, since that name is not reserved by the standard; if the compiler didn't allow that then it would be non-conforming

Comment: @M.M: interestingly, `arm-none-eabi-gcc` toolchain finds `gmtime_r` even with `-std=c99` without any feature macros. The `time.h` it pulls in has no `#ifdef` guards around `gmtime_r` or `localtime_r`.