# std=c99 on gcc 4.3.3, I get warning: implicit declaration of function ‘gmtime_r’

Tags: c99

Using an admittedly old compiler, I'm trying to compile code that uses functions like `nan()`, `swprintf()`, and other C99 features. I add the `-std=c99` argument to CFLAGS, and those issues get fixed, but now I'm seeing

```
warning: implicit declaration of function ‘gmtime_r’
```

I tried following the advice in [implicit declaration of function ‘gmtime_r’](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56350544/implicit-declaration-of-function-gmtime-r), but it didn't help.

Did `gmtime_r()` get *removed* from C99 or something?

---

Here's a tiny test program:

```
#include <math.h>
#include <time.h>

int
main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    double x;
    time_t t;
    struct tm tm;

    x = nan("0");
    t = time(NULL);
    gmtime_r(&t, &tm);

    return 0;
}
```

And the results of trying to compile it:

```
$ cc --version
cc (Ubuntu 4.3.3-5ubuntu4) 4.3.3
Copyright (C) 2008 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

$ cc -c foo.c
foo.c: In function ‘main’:
foo.c:12: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘nan’

$ cc -c -std=c99 foo.c
foo.c: In function ‘main’:
foo.c:14: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘gmtime_r’
```

Comment: I don't think `gmtime_r` was ever in any version of the ANSI or ISO C standard.  Your compiler without `-std=c99` probably provides it as a non-ISO extension, but it may be that with `-std=c99` it hews strictly to the standard and switches off all non-standard extensions.

Comment: For more help, how about a [mcve] together with details on your compiler command line, C library version, OS etc.

Comment: Concur with @NateEldredge gmtime_r was not and is not standard C. Instead try `-std=gnu99` to get C99 with GNU extensions (assuming a suitable version of glibc, because this is implemented mostly in the library not the compiler) i.e. the C99 counterpart of the gnu89 you probably get by default.

Comment: I want the source cod to be compatible with Mac and Windows as well. Probably simplest to not use gmtime_r(). Thanks for your advice everybody.